# Detect EOF on a fgets While Loop

Tags: c, sockets, inputstream, eof, fgets

I'm looping through each line of a TCP socket input using `fdopen` and `fgets` like this:

```
int connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
FILE *f;
char line[1024];

f = fdopen(connfd, "a+");
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) {
    printf("%s", line);
}

printf("EOF");
fclose(f);
```

The problem is that it looks like `fgets` never returns `NULL` for some strange reason. Is there any other way to check for `EOF`?

Comment: If `fgets` doesn't return `NULL`, then there is no `EOF` in your buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll only receive and end of file on a socket if the socket gets closed.

If you need to stop reading while keeping the socket open, you need to define a protocol for that.

Comment: You'll only get EOS if the *connection* gets closed *by the peer.*